# Achieving such realistic looking secondary volumes that look like realistic clouds with sharp edges

Tags: rendering, node-editor, shaders, lighting, volumetrics

I was able to figure out that there are a two kinds of volume cubes here , one is covering the whole terrain and smaller ones creating those clouds.

How do I achieve such realistic volumes which blend perfectly?

I just wanna know how are those smaller volumes created. Is it noise node with color ramp or  are there like custom maps? Cause those volumes have those sharp edges like in real life , any tutorial or suggestion would be helpful.

[image]

[image]